# Rotation Point Troubles in Java

Tags: java, swing, 3d, rotation

## Bit of back story on my project (because your probably going to say, "Just use OpenGL.")

#### a.k.a. The Reason I Hate OpenGL

So, my computer is around 7 years old, with OpenGL 3.30 on my hardware (Using an ATI Radeon HD 4300/4500), and I really wanted to make my own 3D game engine using OpenGL. Long story very short, shaders are broken for me (detail at bottom). So, I said screw it I'm going to make my own 3D renderer. I got the rendering done, but I need help on rotations.

## The More Boring Story of why this happened

Well, the truth is I started making my own engine because my laptop was too old to follow the tutorial, so I started work on a 2D engine with a cool parallax system, then it hit me. The reason why I said the story about my computer being to old is because that is really when I started thinking about rotation on a whole different level.

### The Code

This is where the problems started:

```
x = (float) ((x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)) - z * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot))));
    z = (float) (z * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)) - x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)));
```

*I think I see the problem, I think I need to add zsin(cameraRot) to xcos(cameraRot)*

I've even drawn out how Sine and Cosine functions work, mainly because I was also working on a water effect at the time, and I thought, "I should be able to use sin (and only sin) to rotate." I was wrong (obviously). I have also used a graphing calculator (TI-83+ from 1999, not 2011) to graph those functions (they were a bit different, and yes I used the graphing mode where you could input both X and Y values). I'm trying out some stuff right now, and I think I see the main problem. The Z rotation uses the X rotation, but the X rotation uses the Z coordinate (If that was complicated, I'll break it down: We need to use the original X value to calculate the rotation for the Z value, but we instead use the X value after it's changed to a rotated X, which would make a huge difference).

It doesn't work at all. cameraRot (rotation) is constantly increasing, but there is no effect.
Here's the code for rendering:

```
g.drawRect((int) (x / (z - main.camZ) - 256 / (z - main.camZ) / 2),(int) (0 - 256 / (z - main.camZ) / 2),(int) (256 / (z - main.camZ)),(int) (256 / (z - main.camZ)));
```

But it screws up rendering. Yes, I know that I'm drawing a square, but the previous one I made (on a laptop) was more complete, but used the same rendering algorithm and broke when I tried adding in rotations, every object appeared to be at 0,0,1.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?
Is it from the rendering or the equation? (I'm going to save you the trouble and tell you its the rotation equation.

Just a little side note, I accidentally made that rendering algorithm.

### How the Shaders were Broken

I tried using uniforms with VertexShaders but they only work with Fragment Shaders. The tutorial I followed used "#version 330" (like me) but they had OpenGL version 4.3 (and they were using java) and I had version 3.30 (and used java).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so I was just dumb.

```
x = (float) ((x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)) - z * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot))));
z = (float) (z * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)) - x * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(main.cameraRot)));
```

The reason why I was dumb is because what you would do is (simplified, using `double`s):

```
double tempX = x; 
x = tempX * Math.cos(theta) - z * Math.sin(theta);
z = tempX * Math.sin(theta) + z * Math.cos(theta);
```

Two years later, and I've written this equation so many times now that it is literally going to haunt me forever. Even after I die.

Now to look at something I said:

> *I think I see the problem, I think I need to add zsin(cameraRot) to xcos(cameraRot)*

Not even close. The whole issue I was had the order of `z` and `x` wrong for the `z` equation, as well as I didn't store the `x` in a temporary variable before doing the operations. If you don't do that, it doesn't rotate correctly on the `z` axis.

I might as well add in some notes to this obscure question that's actually quite easy to figure out. If you have `200` objects, each calling `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` twice each, that's highly inefficient. The very least you could do is store the resultant `Math.sin()` and `Math.cos()` values in their own variable, but that's just scratching the surface.

Instead of making it so each object calculates the sine and cosine *individually*, you make a Camera class that holds all the positional and rotational data for the camera, as well as the screen dimensions. This is so that a rectangle sized `1.0 x 1.0` is proportional to a screen. In non-square aspect ratios (e.g. 16:9, 4:3), you can see some stretching going on. The easy way to fix this is to pass the screen's width or height for both `screenWidth` and `screenHeight`. The harder way let's you use any FoV, but that's another day.

```
public class Camera {
    
    // Position variables, X is horizontal, Y is vertical, Z is fordical (forward and backward)
    private double x, y, z;
    private double rot;
    
    private double cos;
    private double sin;
    
    // Variables pertaining to the screen
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;
    
    public Camera(double x, double y, double z, double rot, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        
        setScreenDimensions(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        setPosition(x, y, z);
        setRotation(rot);
        
    }
    
    public void setScreenDimensions(int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
        
        this.screenWidth  = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
        
    }
    public int getScreenWidth() {...}
    public int getScreenHeight() {...}
    
    public void setPosition(double x, double y, double z) {...}
    public void setRotation(double rot) {
        
        // Update the rotation variable
        this.rot = rot;
        // Update the trig values
        cos = Math.cos(rot);
        sin = Math.sin(rot);
        
    }
    
    // Position Getters
    public double getX() {...}
    public double getY() {...}
    public double getZ() {...}
    
    // Position Setters
    public void setX(double x) {...}
    public void setY(double y) {...}
    public void setZ(double z) {...}
    
    
    public double getRotation() { return rot; }

    public double getCos() { return cos; }
    public double getSin() { return sin; }
    
}
```

and then when you transform from `world-space` (3D) to `screen-space` (2D), you would do (using Java Swing because that's what I was using at the time of asking this question):

```
// somewhere in a class, probably the base GameObject class. If it's in an util class, make it "public static", and if it's in the Camera class, it would be "public". 
protected Point transform(Camera camera, double x, double y, double z) {
    
    double transX = x - camera.getX();
    double transY = y - camera.getY();
    double transZ = z - camera.getZ();
    
    double rotX   = transX * camera.getCos() - transZ * camera.getSin();
    double rotZ   = transX * camera.getSin() + transZ * camera.getCos();
    
    int pointX = (transX * camera.getScreenWidth() ) / transZ;
    int pointY = (y      * camera.getScreenHeight()) / transZ;
    
    return new Point(pointX, pointY);
    
}
```

Bam now we've optimized the rendering routine. At least, as far as a sane person would go. If you're really religious about optimization (like I sometimes am), you can probably do some crazy stuff. The real crazy stuff happens when you get to C++ and use pointers, but that's beyond the scope of this Java question. Hell, even going into the optimization part is sort of beyond the scope of the question, but it's my question and I think I reserve the right to answer it as I see fit, as long as it benefits anybody reading my answer.

*note: I wrote this late at night so I apologize for any errors, will fix in the morning!*

*side-note: it's not like anybody's gonna read this anyways :)*